# Eclipse (atollic) Pre-Build command format

Tags: eclipse, build, eclipse-cdt

I'm using Eclipe-Atollic to build for a STM32 micro. Running Windows 10 and TortoiseSvn. Im trying to get the Svn version into my code using the Tortoise "svnversion" command.

I'm trying to add the following command to the Pre-build steps in Eclipse-atollic under  "Project Properties >> C/C++ Build >> Settings >> Build Steps >> Pre-build steps" .

`svnversion > Src\svnvers.inc`

This works fine from the Command prompt, but when I use the Eclipse builder - I get the following error message:

```
Info: Internal Builder is used for build
svnversion > Src\svnvers.inc 
svnversion: E020024: Error resolving case of '>'
```

After the initial error, I've tried a variety of combinations of " and \ escapes, but without success.

Looking for any guidance on how to configure Eclipse to execute this command.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

OK, If anyone else needs to know, I used "cmd -c" to execute the command, so what worked was:

`cmd -c svnversion > Src\svnvers.inc`